Does each ovary release an egg with multiple uterus?
If I understand correctly, uterus didelphys is when the uterus is split in two, creating two uterus connected to only one ovary.
Usually only one ovary release an egg for a given cycle, but since everything is separated in this case, this would mean that only one is fertile at any given time.
I tried asking a gynecologist but was told that it doesn't matter, without any details.
So, in case of uterus didelphys, does each ovary release an egg each cycle? If not, how does it work?

Welcome Telrunya. Please remember to show your own attempts to answer the question, what you searched and found. Showing prior research is a requirement here.  For reference, see our [ask] section of the [help].

Remember to link to your sources when you edit.

In your first sentence, are you meaning that the uteri are each connected to one ovary, or that both are connected to the same ovary?

@anongoodnurse I'm aware of that, but I was hinting that the wording is unclear.
